# sybase enhancment

Tags: stored-procedures, sybase

Do I need to modify the store procedures if sybase version is enhanced

Comment: depends on what you use in your SPs...

Comment: What is the relation with Java?

Comment: it is nothing related to java, I want to know if there is a difference between store procedures written for sybase version 12.5 and 15.

Answer (score 1):

The changes which may be required really depends on the version. There are known changes which are required for migration to ASE15 or higher from a lower version due to the way the optimiser has been improved for internal parallelism.

More info here on these specific code changes for ASE15 upgrades (or higher):

http://sapassets.edgesuite.net/sapcom/docs/2016/09/f69a1674-8a7c-0010-82c7-eda71af511fa.pdf

My experience would be migrating to ASE15 or higher from any lower version needs extensive checking for query plan changes as join order or other changes may be seen. You should really get runtimes for execution of any key critical proc on the old version and compare with the higher version.

Another thing to you need to be aware of is reserved words may change between ASE versions, so a column name which was allowed in an earlier version may now be prohibited. You can check the new version documentation for guidance and Sybase provide a reserved word checking procedure to check these before you upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you've written your stored procs they may need modified but I highly doubt it unless you're using esoteric things or querying system tables directly (they changed a bunch of sys* tables so if you are using them, you might get bad data).

Sybase generally keeps backward compatibility and I'm not aware of any major T-SQL deprecations in 15 (rowcnt() and some traceflags). ASE 15 has a greatly enhanced query processor but if it screws up your queries you can back it out to ASE 12.5 mode.

Anyway, as always you should test out your upgrade beforehand, but I doubt you'll see many issues.

Comment: One I'm aware of is that in 12.5 you can create a nullable field from a non-nullable field in the SELECT list of a SELECT INTO using the ISNULL function.  In 15 that's changed.  Ref: http://groups.google.com/group/sybase.public.ase.upgrades+migration/browse_thread/thread/404dd9c2c397fff7#

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your code. Most of the code should work properly and should not have any issues as Sybase did not deprecate T-SQL commands. But when you upgrade you should upgrade your code as well to take full advantage of new version. Otherwise you are paying for new version but still running on old version.

I would suggest that you check whether the logic implemented in proc could be written in a better way in new version, if yes go ahead and make the changes to use new features.

Answer (score 0):

We did the migration from 12.7 to 15.0, and we had to change few stored procedures wrt to usage of temp tables etc.,